# Count how many files exist in a specific branch in git

Tags: git

I have git repository that has some branches in it.
I want to get the number of files existing in a specific branch. If possible then make list of files.

For example:

```
-- branch: master
   |-components
   | |-- abc.html
   | |-- def.html
   | |-- ghi.html
   |-static
   | |--main.js
   | |--style.css
   |-index.html
```

In the above master branch we can see the number of files is 6.

Is there any command to find out the number of files in a specific branch? If possible then show the list of files.

Answer (score 4):

[`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) can be used to list files in a given commit.

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r master
```

In a repo with two files `foo` and `bar/baz` this will print

```
bar/baz
foo
```

If you want just the number of entries, just use `wc`:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r master | wc -l
```